# Manipulation of two-dimensional arrays: add rows and columns

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, addition

The problem is that it does not show me the resultsadd rows and columns, it does not make the corresponding sums.

Another detail is that I do not print correctly the phrase of the sum of the row, since I omit the is:
The same happens when printing the columns.

The errors on the screen are:

> ```
> p1.c: In function ‘sum’:
> p1.c:34:8: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>     suma= suma + A[i][j];
> p1.c:36:10: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
>    printf("La suma de la fila %i", i+1, " es: %i\n", suma);
> p1.c: In function ‘sumc’:
> p1.c:47:9: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>     sumac= sumac + A[i][j];
> p1.c:49:10: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
>    printf("La suma de la columa %i", j+1, " es: %i\n ", sumac);
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 2
#define N 3

void sum();
void sumc();
int main(void){

    int A[M][N];

    printf("Este programa lee una matriz y suma de manera independiente las filas y las columnas de esta\n");
    printf("Ingrese las entradas de la matriz\n");
    for(int i=0; i<M; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {   
            scanf("%i", &A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    sum(&A[M][N]);
    sumc(&A[M][N]);
}

void sum(int *A[M][N]){
    for(int i=0; i<M; i++)
    {
        int suma=0;
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {   
            suma= suma + A[i][j];
        }
        printf("La suma de la fila %i", i+1, " es: %i\n", suma);
    }
    return;
}

void sumc(int *A[M][N]){
    for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
    {
        int sumac=0;
        for(int i=0; i<M; i++)
        {   
            sumac= sumac + A[i][j];
        }
        printf("La suma de la columa %i", j+1, " es: %i\n ", sumac);
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to learn bit more pointers & *how to pass 2D array to a function*. when you are passing `2D` array to a function & in that function you need to catch with **pointer to an array** not with double pointer.

Also your `printf` statement is wrong.

```
printf("La suma de la fila %i", i+1, " es: %i\n", suma);
```

should be

```
printf("La suma de la fila %i es: %i\n",i+1, suma);
```

Here is the modified code

```
#define M 2
#define N 3
void sum(int (*A)[N],int r,int c){ /* r is row & c is column */
        for(int i=0; i<r; i++) {
                int suma=0;
                for(int j=0; j<c; j++) {
                        suma= suma + A[i][j];
                }
                printf("La suma de la fila %i es: %i\n",i+1, suma);
        }
        return;
}

void sumc(int (*A)[N],int r,int c){
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++){
                int sumac=0;
                for(int i=0; i<r; i++) {
                        sumac= sumac + A[i][j];
                }
                printf("La suma de la columa %i  es: %i\n ",j+1, sumac);
        }
        return;
}
int main(void){

        int A[M][N];

        printf("Este programa lee una matriz y suma de manera independiente las filas y las columnas de esta\n");
        printf("Ingrese las entradas de la matriz\n");
        for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
                for(int j=0; j<N; j++) {
                        scanf("%i", &A[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
        sum(A,M,N);/* passing 2D aray base address,no of row and no of column */
        printf("\n=====\n");
        sumc(A,M,N);
}
```

Comment: This uses the C90 constructs, so it is maximally portable, but simultaneously minimally flexible.  In C99 (mandatorily) and C11 (optionally), there is support for variable length arrays (VLAs).  Those require a slightly different calling sequence for the functions, with the sizes appearing before the the array, but then a single function can be used for any size of (`int`) array.

Comment: @achal  why:    void sumc(int (*A)[N],int r,int c){   only use (*A)[N] and not use (*A)[M][N]?

Comment: what is `int (*A)[row][col]` ? its _pointers to an array to an array_, its not needed to catch `2D` array.

Comment: @achal so why your only use (*A)[N] ? I mean why only use col?
if it is a 2D array. Why is not it necessary?

Comment: Bcz from main function you are passing 1D or 2D or 3D array you are just passing base address of that array, now how `sum()` function come to know whether I am receiving 1D or 2D or 3D array address, bcz it's just an address. So have to specify/send how many rows or columns.